# Kafka Stream State Store using RocksDB-Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Is it possible to configure Kafka Streams to use [RockesDB-Cloud](https://github.com/rockset/rocksdb-cloud) rather than the  default RockesDB database as storage engine? If so, is there any configuration recipe? I would like to persist data on S3 buckets instead of local filesystem.

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. You would need to implement a custom `StateStore` that integrates RocksDB-Cloud. It's not easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback